# Doctrine , Symfony3 Select range of dates from a table using intervals

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

to make everything clear i have these two tables

```
table 1
-------------------------------
id | name | email | created_at 
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:01
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:01
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:01
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:02
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:04
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:04
-------------------------------
```

---

```
table 2
-------------------------------
id | name | email | created_at
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:03
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:03
x  | x    |  x    | 2016:09:05
-------------------------------
```

the user will have to pick two dates start and end 
lets say he\she picked start = 2016:09:01 and end = 2016:09:07
so i need a result to be displayed like this

```
result
-------------------------------
num_of_recs_t1 | num_of_recs_t2 | day
3              | 0              | 2016:09:01
1              | 0              | 2016:09:02
0              | 2              | 2016:09:03
2              | 0              | 2016:09:04
0              | 1              | 2016:09:05
0              | 0              | 2016:09:06
0              | 0              | 2016:09:07
```

i am using Symfony 3 with doctrine and to be honest i dont even think i can make with normal mysql commands

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you working with Doctrine ORM? Or just DBAL?

Comment: @dragoste with ORM

Comment: If you use ORM then you should think in terms of objects, not tables. Doctrine will be much easier to understand this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in controller

```
$db = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();

$data = $db->fetchAll("
select
  t1.num_of_recs as num_of_recs_t1,
  t2.num_of_recs as num_of_recs_t2,
  t1.created_at
from
  (
    select created_at, count(*) as num_of_recs
    from table_1
    group by created_at
  ) t1
  join (
    select created_at, count(*) as num_of_recs
    from table_2
    group by created_at
  ) t2
    on t1.created_at = t2.created_at
order by
  t1.created_at");

dump($data);
```

Comment: but this one won't get the missing dates such as 06-09 and 07-09

Comment: Fill array with zeros for empty dates by php, I think that it is impossible to make it only by sql